# Multiple Correspondence Analysis percentages, and points near to one axis

Tags: pca, correspondence-analysis

I have done a multiple correspondence analysis based on 10 factors: every factor is a `Yes`or `No`question.

The first factor give 22.3% of the total variance and the second 13.6%. I am used to Principal Component Analysis (PCA) and to having a high percentage (>70%).

Question1: Is a total percentage of 35% (22+13) enough for an MCA?

Question2: base on the image attached, is there any implication when the variables are close to the second axis?

Any other comment about the MCA I have done is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Correspondence analysis is an analysis of contingency table (such as frequency cross-table). What is the dimensionality of your table? Can you show us your table?

Comment: 10 variables and every variable have two levels. (20,20)

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand your frequency cross-tabulation. I even suspect that you may be doing something wrong. Show the table please.